# AES 128 Decryption with CBC mode in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cryptography

I am using `CommonCrypto` to decrypt an encrypted MP3 file getting from server.
Actually the server side uses **AES 128** bit encryption with **CBC** mode and `PKCS5Padding`.So I want to decrypt it in the same manner.

I use the code below for decryption.

```
    #import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h

func testCrypt(data:NSData, keyData:NSData, ivData:NSData, operation:CCOperation) -> NSData? {
    let keyBytes = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(keyData.bytes)
    print("keyLength   = \(keyData.length), keyData   = \(keyData)")

    let ivBytes = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(ivData.bytes)
    print("ivLength    = \(ivData.length), ivData    = \(ivData)")

    let dataLength = Int(data.length)
    let dataBytes  = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes)
    print("dataLength  = \(dataLength), data      = \(data)")

    let cryptData: NSMutableData! = NSMutableData(length: Int(dataLength) + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
    let cryptPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(cryptData.mutableBytes)
    let cryptLength  = size_t(cryptData.length)

    let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128)
    let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
    let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

    var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

    let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
        algoritm,
        options,
        keyBytes, keyLength,
        ivBytes,
        dataBytes, dataLength,
        cryptPointer, cryptLength,
        &numBytesEncrypted)

    if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
        cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
        print("cryptLength = \(numBytesEncrypted), cryptData = \(cryptData)")

    } else {
        print("Error: \(cryptStatus)")
    }

    return cryptData;
}
```

How can I specify the **CBC** mode and `PKCS5Padding` in this code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"How can I specify the CBC mode and PKCS5Padding in this code?"* It's the default, so you should be done already. [PKCS#5 padding and PKCS#7 padding are the same thing.](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding) If not, please show some example inputs, outputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 2):

The Block size of AES using always **16** bytes . 
And block size of `PKCS5Padding` is defined **8** byte . so you can not use the combination like `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` .
you can only use  `PKCS5Padding` when your block size is not more than **8** bytes.

*Another things*

`CCCrypt` is default working on `CBC`  mode , so in that case you do not need to mention `CBC` mode . As instance , If you want to `ECB` mode that time you should mentioned `kCCOptionECBMode`

Unfortunately Apple documentation do not have `PKCS5Padding` . You can use `PKCS7Padding` alternative of `PKCS5Padding` when your block size will exactly **8** bytes .

Comment: While PKCS#5 padding is defined only for up to 8 bytes that is just the definition, in practice PKCS#5 is interoperable with PKCS#7. Many libraries just have not updated the documentation from PKCS#5 to PKCS#7. Essentially both PKCS#5 and PKCS#7 set all the pad bytes to the point of pad bytes.